# How to turn on/off Adobe Flash settings for Microsoft Edge using registry editor?

Tags: flash, registry, microsoft-edge

Trying to turn on Adobe Flash settings in Microsoft Edge using Windows Registry(Regedit) modification, but it doesn't reflect in the browser. Not looking for a manual or GPO approach, since it needs to be eventually done on a large scale.

Came across and tried this,
[To enable Flash Policy for Edge](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.MicrosoftEdge::AllowFlash) , and also tried the below approach:

```
$RegistryPath = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Addons"

New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "FlashPlayerEnabled" -Value "1" -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
```

(Had to create the Addons folder as it wasn't available).
But, they don't seem to reflect the change to the browser. Also tried exporting and comparing the registry by manually turning on/off in the browser to see what values were being changed and even that didn't showcase any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links you have mentioned in the original post shows the correct registry key settings.

> Path: HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Addons
>
> Value name: FlashPlayerEnabled
>
> Value type: REG_DWORD

I have tested it on my side and it is enabling/ disabling the flash for the Edge legacy browser.

Reference:

[Allow Adobe Flash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/adobe-settings-gp#allow-adobe-flash)

**Edit:-**

As you had informed that you want to set the policy for the MS Edge (Chromium) browser.

I found some Flash-related policies that may help you to fix your issue.

1. [RunAllFlashInAllowMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#runallflashinallowmode)
2. [Default Adobe Flash setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#default-adobe-flash-setting)
3. [Allow the Adobe Flash plug-in on specific sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#allow-the-adobe-flash-plug-in-on-specific-sites)
4. [Block the Adobe Flash plug-in on specific sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#block-the-adobe-flash-plug-in-on-specific-sites)

You can try to refer to the docs and try to set the desired policy.

Comment: Does enabling/disabling directly on the browser, change its respective registry value as well for you?
I've Edge v84(latest) on w10, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This policy is for MS Edge (EdgeHTML) legacy browser. It will not work for the MS Edge (chromium) browser. I will search whether there is any policy for the MS Edge Chromium browser to disable the Flash and try to inform you.

Comment: Please check my updated answer may help you to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. I already tried 1st & 3rd approach earlier. Now using 1st and 2nd policies approach worked. Thanks a lot Deepak.